# Tensorflow basic example - Variables initialization

Tags: tensorflow

I am having this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(1000, size=10000)
x = tf.Variable(data, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(5*x*x-3*x+15, name='y')

model = tf.initialize_all_variables();

with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(model)
    print (s.run(y))
```

I am trying to implement an exercise related to tensorflow variables but it fails with the following error:

> Attempting to use uninitialized value x_20     [[Node: x_20/read =
>   IdentityT=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@x_20"],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I also tried to initialize x with a constant but it still fails. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your definition of `y` that's a bit funny.

Your code currently makes a variable `y` and *initializes* it to `5*x*x-3*x+15`

Maybe you just mean that the value of `y` is calculated from the value of `x`:

```
y=5*x*x-3*x+15
```

If you actually want to initialize a new variable `y` with the initial value of that expression over `x`, then you need to use `x.initialized_value()`:

```
x = tf.Variable(data, name='x')
x0 = x.initialized_value()
y = tf.Variable(5*x0*x0-3*x0+15, name='y')
```

The traceback you're getting is coming from the fact that the initialize operation is trying to initialize `y`, before initializing `x`.

The `.initialized_value()` method enforces the order.

See: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variables/index.html#initialization-from-another-variable

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I had to provide a constant value to the variable x. 
So I changed this line:

```
x = tf.Variable(data, name='x')
```

to the following line:

```
x = tf.constant(data, name='x')
```

It seems that a `variable` must be given a `constant` value.